# How to convert MySQL returned date time to more readable string

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table of events on MySQL like

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ts TIMESTAMP,
    dt DATETIME
);
```

Now when I query the table for `dt` I am getting `2018-01-04 00:00:00`. How can I convert it to format of `Jan, 4` to be displayed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) function

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dt, "%b, %e") as dt FROM events
```

Additionally, you can use same function for `INSERT` statements

```
INSERT INTO events(`ts`, `dt`)
VALUES ('some timestamp', DATE_FORMAT('2018-01-15 00:00:00', '%b, %e'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot s Erwin. ANy idea how can I acive same process on insert? I mean if user inserted `Jan, 5` on client side how can I insert to database in standard database format of `2018-01-05 00:00:00`

Comment: @MonaCoder this answer exactly gave you what you asked for. Now you are expanding the question?

Comment: @ryantxr, Doesn't hurt to add some helpful codes. MonaCoder, try to practice adding all possible problems to your question next time. See edited answer :)

Comment: Great, I really appreciate your time and effort sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$val = "2018-01-04 00:00:00";
$time = date_create($val);
echo date_format($time, "M, j");

// output: Jan, 4
```